# Col Span Split For First td cell with table header

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="1">Header</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2" >Header</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="1">Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td colspan="2">Col 3</td>
    <td  colspan="1">Col 1</td>
    <td  colspan="1">Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

From the above code i need to share first td with two th cells. how it is possible to share the first td cell to share with th if td colspan is greater than th colspan. I got error in first td cell only while sharing with two th headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```html
<table border="1">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:25%;" />
    <col style="width:25%;" />
    <col style="width:25%;" />
    <col style="width:25%;" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" colspan="1">Header</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="2" >Header</th>
    <th scope="col" colspan="1">Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td colspan="2">Col 3</td>
    <td  colspan="1">Col 1</td>
    <td  colspan="1">Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you.. it is working fine..is it necessary to add  "<col style="width:25%;" />" for every td cell if i have n number of td?

Comment: <TR id=tr1>
<TH colSpan=1 scope=col>October  </TH>
<TH   colSpan=2 scope=col>November  </TH>
</TR>

<TR id=tr_WeekHeader>
<TH colSpan=2>W44</TH>
<TH>W45</TH>
</TR>  is it possible in two th also if they are in seperated TR?

Comment: <table border=1>
 <colgroup>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
  </colgroup>

<TR id=tr1> 
<TH colSpan=1>October </TH>
<TH colSpan=2>November </TH> </TR>
<TR id=tr_WeekHeader> 
<TH colSpan=2>W44</TH> <TH colSpan=1>W45</TH> 
</TR>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

The width of the td normally depends on the data in nth td of all rows.

```html
   <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th colspan="2">Savings</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$8000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```